# JMeter Connection Issues

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to do a very basic Hello World-type test using JMeter but I'm already running into issues. I've followed the instructions detailed in this video:
https://youtu.be/mXGcBvWYl-U

After some initial problems (it wasn't saving my tests so I had to download a version 5.5 snapshot I found in another Stackoverflow post) I got it to where the threads were being sent out, but they all returned errors. In the stacktrace I got this message:

```
ERROR o.a.j.v.b.g.TextGraphiteMetricsSender: Error writing to Graphite: Connection refused
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:669) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:549) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:645) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.graphite.SocketOutputStreamPoolFactory.create(SocketOutputStreamPoolFactory.java:76) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.graphite.SocketOutputStreamPoolFactory.makeObject(SocketOutputStreamPoolFactory.java:47) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.graphite.SocketOutputStreamPoolFactory.makeObject(SocketOutputStreamPoolFactory.java:33) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.create(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1073) ~[commons-pool2-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:348) ~[commons-pool2-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:271) ~[commons-pool2-2.9.0.jar:2.9.0]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.graphite.TextGraphiteMetricsSender.writeMetrics(TextGraphiteMetricsSender.java:109) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.graphite.TextGraphiteMetricsSender.writeAndSendMetrics(TextGraphiteMetricsSender.java:103) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.graphite.GraphiteBackendListenerClient.sendMetrics(GraphiteBackendListenerClient.java:182) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.graphite.GraphiteBackendListenerClient.teardownTest(GraphiteBackendListenerClient.java:363) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.BackendListener.testEnded(BackendListener.java:375) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.BackendListener.testEnded(BackendListener.java:383) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfEnd(StandardJMeterEngine.java:218) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:493) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) [?:?]
```

I have no idea what Graphite is but I think I must be doing something wrong. Is it possible that the website she used in the video as an example changed their GET protocol or something? I also tried with Wikipedia but I'm a little unclear on where to go from here now. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the page I was looking at was not open to API calls. When I tried a different page it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have a [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Backend_Listener) somewhere in your Test Plan and I fail to see it in the video so check your test plan and remove the Backend Listener from it, this way you should be able to replicate the exercise.

If you want to see the test results in the real time somewhere in Grafana take a look at the following materials:

- [Real-time results](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html)
- [How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter Non-GUI Results](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results)

Comment: Yeah I didn't really know what it was but I thought it might help me understand the errors more. I double-checked and removing it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Okay, that does remove the error I mentioned so technically you did answer the question, but I guess that error wasn't really the problem because the threads are still failing.

Comment: 1 11:57:18.991 Users 1-1  0 Warning 862 0 0 0
2 11:57:19.093 Users 1-2  0 Warning 862 0 0 0
3 11:57:19.191 Users 1-3  0 Warning 862 0 0 0
4 11:57:19.294 Users 1-4  0 Warning 862 0 0 0
5 11:57:19.396 Users 1-5  0 Warning 862 0 0 0
6 11:57:19.495 Users 1-6  0 Warning 862 0 0 0
7 11:57:19.595 Users 1-7  0 Warning 862 0 0 0
8 11:57:19.691 Users 1-8  0 Warning 862 0 0 0
9 11:57:19.793 Users 1-9  0 Warning 862 0 0 0
10 11:57:19.896 Users 1-10  0 Warning 862 0 0 0